# How to open dbs file (SQLBase)

Tags: database, odbc, sqlbase

I have a file with an extension ".dbs". All that I know that it's Gupta SQLBase DB version 9.1
I've downloaded and installed SQLBase 11.6 but I don't have any idea how to load it.
Google didn't tell me anything intelligible.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a querying tool called SQLTalk shipped naturaly with the SQLBase engine. 
You should read through the online help manuals for a start.....[SQLBase User guide](http://support.unify.com/Docs/SQLBaseDoc116/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm) as there are many ways to get into the .dbs

Answer (score 0):

02/10/2017 Update on this answer. 
See the attached SQLBase Language reference , specifically 'UNLOAD' to get your data and schema out of v9  , and then 'LOAD' to get you data into v11.6 .
The attached manual is for v9 , but LOAD and UNLOAD work the same no matter which version of SQLbase . See: [SQLBase Language Reference](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~priit/(I216)%20Ab-de%20administreerimine/SQLBase%20admin%20juhendid/LANG.PDF)